# where's the localhost alias set so that URLs can be adjusted?

Tags: php, apache, url, wampserver

I can't for the life of me understand where the previous developer set up the configuration of the localhost system so that the application can run with a URL like:

`http://my-app/index.php`
instead of 
`http://localhost/index.php`

I've checked the following files but can't find `my-app` anywhere:

`httpd-vhosts.conf`, the windows `hosts` file, `wampmanager.tpl`, `wampmanager.ini`, `.htaccess`, and files inside the `wamp/bin/apache/Apachexxxx/` folder. Where on earth else should I look for this mysterious setting? The application's running on wampserver 2.1

Comment: DNS, perhaps? That'd be something OFF your server, unless you're running your own dns server.

Comment: You want set only local web alias with URL? Or access to local from everywhere?

Comment: No, nothing off the server. Everything is on this single machine, and all usage too is on this machine only. So access and control are all on this single machine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! It's so simple I can't believe I'd been cracking my head over this for days.

The old developer had simply renamed the computer name, from (right-click) My Computer's Properties. The name was changed to `my-app`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

check your `hosts` file. Since your running windows its in the following path

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `my-app.com` to browser, open website under the `C:/wamp/www/my-app/` folder.

#### About WAMP SERVER

Append to file below `VirtualHost` block.

**Important:** Below codes based under the `C:/wamp/www/my-app/`files. You can change what you want.

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@my-app.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/my-app/"
    ServerName my-app.com
    ServerAlias www.my-app.com
    ErrorLog "logs/my-app.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/my-app.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

#### About Windows

Append line like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

127.0.0.1       my-app.com
127.0.0.1       www.my-app.com
```

And **RESTART** your **WAMP** server..